# SQL substring non greedy regex

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, substring

I have data like

```
http://www.linz.at/politik_verwaltung/32386.asp
```

stored in a text column. I thought a non-greedy extraction with

```
select substring(turl from '\..*?$') as ext from tdata
```

would give me .asp but instead it still `?greedely` results in

```
 .linz.at/politik_verwaltung/32386.asp
```

How can I only match against the last occurence of dot `.`?
Using Postgresql 9.3

Comment: Could you provide expected output example?

Comment: `.asp` is what you expect right

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise, yes, .asp would be what I expect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\.[^.]*$` matches `.` followed by any number of non-dot characters followed by end-of-string:

```
# select substring('http://www.linz.at/politik_verwaltung/32386.asp' 
  from '\.[^.]*$');
 substring 
-----------
 .asp
(1 row)
```

As for why the non-greedy quantifiers do not work here is that they still start matching *as soon as possible* while still trying to match as short as possible from there on.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\.[\w]*$
```

Here is how it works:

all the `word` characters (`\w`), any numbers of them with `*`, between `dot` (`\.`) and the `end of the string` (`$`), with the last `.` itself.

**Note**: updated the answer, now will capture the strings ends with `.`.